# Is it correct to close TCP connection directly - without closing more high-level layer?

Tags: java, tcp, smpp

For example I communicate with SMS center throgh smpp protocol, and SMSC send to me **FIN** flag by tcp protocol instead of sending **unbind** throgh SMPP. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unbind operation is optional, besides, it's usually sent by the ESME to the MC, not vice versa.

Even if the MC usually sends unbind before connection close, there might be cases where it cannot do that (for example it detects some protocol error, thus cannot reliably send an unbind operation). In these cases the MC will just close the connection, so in your client you should handle the "naked close" case, too.

Comment: Thank you! Problem is that I cant undestand in my java app when SMSC send FIN flag.

Comment: You should periodically send an enquire_link packet if your connection is otherwise idle. In case the MC closed the connection, you'll get an IOException in your java code.

Comment: Its logical, but please, see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839058/orrect-closing-tcp-connection-throw-java . May be you can help ?